# How do I keep track of index when using a higher order function?

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I was wondering how would I be able to keep track of the index when it comes to higher order classes I'm trying to build a function that takes a [a] list and a function (a->Int->b) which essentially would be f(ai, i) and returns list [b].

I thought of doing something like:

```
higherOrd :: [a]->(a->Int->b)->[b]
higherOrd t f = [f x y | x <- t, y <- [1..length(t)]]
```

for example, if I do `higherOrd (1,2..10) (+)`  I get:

```
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

when I would want to get `[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `zip`:

```
higherOrd :: [a] -> (a -> Int -> b) -> [b]
higherOrd t f = [f x y | (x,y) <- zip f [1..]]
```

this then enumerates over the two lists at the same time. Or we work with a function that Haskell already provides: `zipWith`:

```
higherOrd :: [a] -> (a -> Int -> b) -> [b]
higherOrd t f = zipWith f t [1..]
```